# Glassfish not able to start due to conflict with java (available in jdk and jre) in Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, glassfish

Getting the following exception while starting the glassfish server (in Mac OS with jdk1.7.0_67).

Let me know if you have any suggestion to resolve the java conflict and start the domain successfully. Thanks in Advance.

The below one is result from Mac OS Mavericks -> Terminal

```
> pwd
/Users/arj/glassfish3/bin
> **./asadmin start-domain domain1**

Waiting for domain1 to start .Error starting domain domain1.
The **server exited prematurely with exit code 1.**
Before it died, it produced the following output:

FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
objc[20181]: **Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.**
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    at com.advisory.olympus.util.JavaAgentClass.<clinit>(JavaAgentClass.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:382)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:397)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 7 more
launchctl bsexec failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Command start-domain failed.
```

The same issue occurs if tried through eclipse->glassfish as well...

Comment: I think you might have an application deployed on your Glassfish which throws this error.
First make sure you have no application installed on your GF instance and then try to start it
Otherwise let me know

Comment: @M2je Thanks for the response. Yes, after removing my project dependency jars, the domain started normally. Let me look at the compatibility issue among versions of OS, Java, glassfish, ojdbc and my project Jars.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to **Ojdbc7.jar** resolved the issue.